# Set initial value of DateInputElement

Tags: datepicker, dart

I need to set intial value for DateInputElement. The .dart file has a variable dob with initial value:

```
String dob='01/01/2013'
```

and html has

```dart
<input id='mydob' type='date' name='dob' required='true' bind-value='dob'/>
```

dob is not shown when UI is displayed. The control shows mm/dd/yyyy.
If I select a date on UI, the date value is populated in dob variable.

Although bind-value sets two way binding, still tried setting the value to dob as follows without success:

```dart
<input id='mydob' type='date' name='dob' required='true' value={{dob}}  bind-  value='dob'/>
```

Also tried the following in life cycle events but did not work:

```dart
DateInputElement e = query('#mydob');
e.value=dob;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format you are trying to put into the field is wrong. It's supposed to be `2013-01-01 (YYYY-MM-DD)` according to the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/references.html#refsRFC3339). This is completely independent from dart or any other binding.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that it is nessary to have the 0. So it is 2013-01-01 and not 2013-1-1